# Kubuntu 11.10 running slow and kwin using over 90%

Tags: 11.10, kubuntu

On 2 netbooks that have been upgraded to 11.10 and are set to auto login, I am 
finding that everything is running slow and kwin is at over 90% until I log 
out and log in again and re-enable desktop effects after which it is running 
properly again.

Also, when I log out, I have to log in twice as the first time it only gets to 
the 2nd icon before dumping me back to the login screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it working again with a combination of upgrading to KDE 4.8, adding the xorg-edgers PPA and disabling the "Use OpenGL 2 shaders" option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Kubuntu low-fat settings ?

package:kubuntu-low-fat-settings

> :~$ apt-cache show kubuntu-low-fat-settings
>
> Description: Default settings for Kubuntu Low Fat setups  This package contains the
>   settings used by Kubuntu low fat setups.  Compared to the regular
>   default settings, this package decativates a lot of  non-essential
>   features to gain additional system resources.

"Claydoh" is blogging here: http://dohbuoy.wordpress.com/2011/09/23/slim-it-down/

About the log-in-loop

If you add a new user and log in with it - does the new user have the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

First, switch from OpenGL to XRender from the Desktop Effects settings. If that doesn't work, try `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-low-fat-settings`.